# How to avoid overwriting data when creating a list? Selenium Webdriver, Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to scrape every page on the following website: https://www.top40.nl/top40/2020/week-34 (for each year and weeknumber) by clicking on the song, then move to 'songinfo' and then scrape all data in the table listed there. For this question, I only scraped the title so far.

This the url I use:
url = 'https://www.top40.nl/top40/'

However, when I print the songs_list, it will only return the last title on the website. As such, I believe I am overwriting.

Hopefully someone can explain me which mistake(s) I am making and if there is any easier way to scrape the table on each page, very happy to hear.

Please find my python code below:

````
for year in range(2015,2016):
    for week in range(1,2):
        page_url = url+str(year) + '/' + 'week-' + str(week)
        driver.get(page_url)
        lists = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-linktype='title']")
        
        
        links = []
        for l in lists:
            print(l.get_attribute('href'))
            links.append(l.get_attribute('href'))
        
        for link in links:
            driver.get(link)
            
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='#songinfo']").click()
            
            songs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(""".//*[@id="songinfo"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td""")
            songs_list = []
            for s in songs: 
                print(s.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
                songs_list.append(s.get_attribute('innerHTML'))```
````

Comment: Maybe you could instead save each title to a file. That way, you know you can have a file that you can even use multiple times after parsing the site once. Maybe add more information that you can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `songs_list = []` is inside the `for link in links` loop, so with each new iteration it gets set to an empty list (and then you append to this new, empty list). Once you end all your loops, you only see the `songs_list` created.

The simplest fix is to place the `songs_list = []` line outside all for loops, ex:

```
songs_list = []
for year in range(2015,2016):
    for week in range(1,2):
        # etc
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The simple solution worked perfectly. Just one follow-up question as I do have a lot of whitespace in my output. Is there a simple way to remove that while or after creating the list?

Comment: If the elements in `songs_list` are strings, you could try to filter the whitespace elements using the string `isspace` method. A list comprehension like `filtered_list = [song for song in songs_list if not song.isspace()]` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you again for your response. However this does not seem to work. I add it after the songs_list.append right? Output currently looks likes this: 

My Culture

                                1 Giant Leap

Which causes issues when I want to combine it into one dataframe.. Can I add something to the print function to remove all the tabs and whitespace?

Comment: I notice that you are not able to see the white space in this comment box, but anyway there is a lot of whitespace around '1 Giant Leap'.